# Latex table of contents not visible in sidebar of pdf viewer

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf

I am trying to compile and write my dissertation. For this I have a table of contents being generated using latex.

The table of contents is correctly generated in pdf itself.
However, I cannot see the table of contents in the *sidebar of my pdf viewer*(mac os). Why is this, how can I enable viewing of the table of contents in the sidebar?

Here is a link to the latex template with the entire zip package and a Makefile:
http://mice.cs.columbia.edu/c/d.php?d=109

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The following is the code which is generating the tableofcontents::

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
```

The following are the packages used:

```
%%%
%%% Packages
%%%
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{named}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}

%
% We use the hyperref package and customize it for optimal PDF 
%
\usepackage[dvipdfm,pdftitle={\thesistitle},pdfauthor={\thesisauthor},pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},letterpaper,bookmarks,bookmarksopen=true,pdfstartview={FitH},bookmarksnumbered=true,]{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{pdftex,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}
%\usepackage{hypcap}
```

I get a warning for the following line that may or maynot be relevant::

```
\part{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{refs}
\bibliographystyle{named}
```

The warning is

```
*The anchor of a bookmark and its parent's must not(hyperref) be the same. Added a new anchor*
```

I also get another warning::

```
\fancyhead's `E' option without twoside option is useless
```

The following is a snapshot from preview:
[image]

This is what I would like:

[image]

Comment: the pdfbookmarks are usually generated automatically from the section headings if you use the `hyperref` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using the hyperref package, but for whatever reason I do not see anything in the sidetab. If possible, can you look at the link I sent? I would really like to view it in the sidebar, for navigation purposes when reviewing the document.

Comment: Have you enabled this view https://i.stack.imgur.com/75AC8.png?

Comment: @samcarter Yes, please have a look at the snapshots I just uploaded.

Comment: it is unreasonable to expect people to download a source zip (and the question is archived forever and is meaningless if that link changes) make a small complete document with just a few headings that does not make a pdf bookmark set that you think should do, and add it to your question in a code section (`{}` button in the editor)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I made a small copy of the code, which should be relevant to the problem. I have left the link in case anyone finds it useful

Comment: fragments that can't be run are not really helping anyone help you. However some observations your package use is wrong.  you have specified `[dvips]` to `epsfig` (you should not be using epsfig anyway unless emulating a document from 1988) and specified `dvipdfm` to hyperref. You can't be using both dvi drivers on the same file at the same time, so one of those options is wrong. If you are using dvips but told hyperref you are using dvipdfm it will insert the wrong \specials.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the hint, the problem was because of dvipdfm being used in hyperref options. I think it's conflicting with something and when I remove it I can see the table of contents in the side panel. I will add this as an answer. I'll try and put working code in the future in the questions.

Comment: well are you using dvipdfm to make the pdf (if not it's conflicting with that!)

Comment: I am using : dvips -t letter main.dvi -o main.ps and then ps2pdf main.ps after building using latex command.

Comment: Don't use the dvi/postscript tool chain if you want hyperlinks. Use pdflatex to compile your document directly into pdf.

Comment: `epsfig` has been deprecated for years. Use `graphicx` and read l2tabu.